# WxPython on MSW, DirPickerCtrl using different dialogs over time

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

On MSW, the first time DirPickerCtrl's dialog is shown, it really is a Dir picker :
[image: dirpicker]

But as soon as a directory is selected, further calls to DirPickerCtrl's dialog make appear a FilePicker :
[image]

That's no big deal, but still a little bit inconsistent. Any idea how to prevent this?

EDIT :
Code which duplicates this issue:

```
import wx, wx.adv

app = wx.App(False)

frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World", size=(500,500)) 
panel = wx.Panel(frame) 
sizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
panel.SetSizer(sizer)
widget = wx.DirPickerCtrl(panel, style=wx.DIRP_DEFAULT_STYLE |
                                        wx.DIRP_SMALL |
                                        wx.DIRP_CHANGE_DIR)

widget.SetPath(".")
sizer.Add(widget)

frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I just updated my Question with a stripped down version of the code.

Comment: @benco, what version of wxpython do you use? Can you reproduce it in c++?

Comment: Version is '4.1.1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5' according to `wx.version()`. About C++, I don't currently have an environment (also, didn't write any C++ after 1997, so it's a bit old for me...)